# Compare columns and print smaller and bigger rows

Tags: python, unix, awk

I have 2 files in this way

file 1 has 1 row:

```
6
4 
13 
25 
35 
50  
65 
75 
and so on.....
```

file2 has 1 row in it

```
24
45
76
and so on.....
```

I want to take each value(one at a time) in file2 and compare with file1 and if the value of file1 is less than that number take those value and keep them in list and then sort them according to number and print the largest value

for example:
I took 24 number in file2 and compared with file1 and saw 6,4 and 13 are below that number,then I extract them keep it in list and sort it and print the largest value(i.e. 13)

Comment: are they columns or rows?

Comment: sorry rows,i just did edit

Comment: So, does each file contain a single number on each line ("row") of the data files?

Comment: Can you please show the expected output from the given input?

Comment: yes each file has single number in each line

Comment: 13 35 75 etc.. in each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read each file into a `list`, converting each line to `int`. Then sort both lists to allow us to iterate efficiently,

```
file1 = sorted([int(l) for l in open('file1.txt').read().split()])
file2 = sorted([int(l) for l in open('file2.txt').read().split()])

i = 0
for file2_number in file2:
    while i+1 < len(file1) and file1[i+1] < file2_number:
        i += 1
    print file1[i]
```

This currently prints the answers (`13 35 75`) but you can easily modify it to return a `list` if wanted.

Comment: hi jared,i have a similar question

Comment: now file1 has same 6
4 
13 
25 
35 
50  
65 
75 rows in them and file2 has 2,3,7 rows in them etc..now i want to take a row of file2 and search for higher than that number and print the lowest highest number for example output:4 4 13 etc..

Comment: @user2133307 Just change the while loop to `while i+1 < len(file1) and file1[i] <= file2_number:`. Notice both of these solutions assume you aren't asking for a lower/higher value from file1 where it doesn't actually exist. So, for instance if you're looking for the lowest highest and file1's highest is lower than file2's highest, it will just return the last element of the list. A similar effect for the highest lowest but with the first element.

Answer (score 0):

awk solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {b[FNR]=$0}
END{
        n=asort(b)
        for(j in a)
                for(i=n;i>0;i--)
                        if(b[i]<j){
                                print "for "j" in file2 we found : "b[i]
                                break
                        }
}' file2 file1
```

output:

```
for 45 in file2 we found : 35 
for 76 in file2 we found : 75 
for 24 in file2 we found : 13
```

**Note** : there is room to optimize. if performance is critical, you could consider to (just suggestion)

- sort file1 descending
- sort file2 ascending
- take first from sorted file2, go through file1 from the file1.first, when you find the smaller one, record the position/index `x`
- take the 2nd from sorted file2, from `file1.x` starting compare, when found the right one, update `x`
- till the end of file2

the brute force way will take `O(mxn)` or `O(nxm)` depends on `n` and `m` which one is bigger.

The algorithm above... I didn't  analyze , should be faster than `O(mxn)`.. ;)

both python and awk could do the job. if possible, load the two files into memory. if you have monster files, that's another algorithm problem. e.g. sort huge file

Comment: thank you for the hint,i will let you know once if get the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Using Python, after first reading in all of the lines in file1 and all of the lines in file2 into two separate lists, then you can simply traverse through them, comparing each number from file 1 to each number in file2 like so:

```
#First load each of the lines in the data files into two separate lists
file1Numbers = [6, 4, 13, 25, 35, 50, 65, 75]
file2Numbers = [24, 45, 76]
extractedNumbers = []

#Loops through each number in file2
for file2Number in file2Numbers:

    #Loops through each number in file 
    for file1Number in file1Numbers:

        #Compares the current values of the numbers from file1 and file2
        if (file1Number < file2Number):

            #If the number in file1 is less than the number in file2, add
            #the current number to the list of extracted numbers
            extractedNumbers.append(file1Number)


    #Sorts the list of extracted numbers from least to greatest
    extractedNumbers.sort()

    #Prints out the greater number in the list
    #which is the number located at the end of the sorted list (position -1)
    print extractedNumbers[-1]
```

Comment: This is definitely the most intuitive solution but will run in `O(n^2)` since it compares every element of the first list to the second list (+ overhead of sorting `extractedNumbers` instead of just keeping a max value). Not the best for dealing with long files.

Comment: i was trying this in similar way before,but was confused in getting number out,but now i got it thank you

Comment: i am getting same values for output file,since i have the large files

Comment: That is a good point Jared. In terms of efficiency for large data sets, the method I presented will not be very fast, but it is just one relatively simple way of approaching the problem.